# Input text change checkbox model only once [AngularJS]

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have this

```
<input type="text" ng-click"function1()">
```

And this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="function2()" ng-model="stateCheck">
```

The functions do this:

```
$scope.function1 = function(){
  $scope.stateCheck = false;
}

$scope.function2 = function(){
  $scope.stateCheck = !$scope.stateCheck;
}
```

But the function1 just works the first time. Does anyone know why? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by `just works the first time`?

Comment: the first time i click in the input the state changes, then i click in the checkbox and fine, but then if i click in the input again, the state continues like true. @JacopoSciampi

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-change="function2()" 
ng-model="stateCheck"
```

These two events are conflicting with each other, Basically ng-model makes the $state.stateCheck=true and then functin2() $state.stateCheck=!$state.stateCheck makes it false. Due to this checkbox will always remain unchecked. function1() works fine